# PHP - trying to write function outputs via fwrite into file

Tags: php, function, fwrite

It is late (in Europe anyhow) and my mind is blocked with why I can't find the answer to the above question.

My goal ist to have sth. like a keygen program that first writes into an external .csv or .txt. The rest afterwards can be ignored for now.

Anyhow I can't see how I could write the combined effort of my functions into a file and humbly ask for help.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["codeCount"]))
    $codeCount = $_POST["codeCount"];
if (isset($_POST["digitsCount"]))
    $digitsCount = $_POST["digitsCount"];
if (isset($_POST["blockCount"]))
    $blockCount = $_POST["blockCount"];

#Generieren eines Blocks mit x Digits
function keygen($digitsCount){
    $charpool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"; 
    for ($i=0; $i < $digitsCount; $i++) { 
        $five = substr($charpool, random_int(0, strlen($charpool)-1), 1);
        echo $five;
    }
}

#Wie viele Blöcke soll es geben?
function keygenLong($blockCount, $digitsCount){
    for ($i=0; $i < $blockCount; $i++) { 
        echo keygen($digitsCount);
        if ($i != $blockCount-1) {
            echo "-";   
        }
    }
}


#Wie viele Codes benötigen wir ingesamt?
function codeOutput($codeCount, $blockCount, $digitsCount){
    for ($i=0; $i < $codeCount; $i++) { 
        keygenLong($blockCount, $digitsCount);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

codeOutput($codeCount, $blockCount, $digitsCount);


// $code = "codeOutput";
// $string = $code($codeCount, $blockCount, $digitsCount);

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $file = fopen("keys.txt","w");

    fwrite($file, codeOutput($codeCount, $blockCount, $digitsCount);
);

    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: your writing a hard coded string-to the file currently, what to want to write to it?

Comment: Have your functions `return` values instead of `echo`-ing them out. Then you can assign the values to a variable and write it to your file

Comment: But then the for loop is ignored and I won’t get a dynamic output

Comment: @SamAlex obviously you would collect the values and `return` **after** the loop

Answer (score 0):

Have your functions `return` values instead of `echo`-ing them out. Then you can assign the values to a variable and write it to your file.

For example

```
function keygen($digitsCount){
    $charpool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    for ($i=0; $i < $digitsCount; $i++) { 
        $five[] = substr($charpool, random_int(0, strlen($charpool)-1), 1);
    }
    return implode('', $five);
}

function keygenLong($blockCount, $digitsCount){
    for ($i=0; $i < $blockCount; $i++) { 
        $out[] = keygen($digitsCount);
    }
    return implode('-', $out);
}

function codeOutput($codeCount, $blockCount, $digitsCount){
    for ($i=0; $i < $codeCount; $i++) { 
        $out[] = keygenLong($blockCount, $digitsCount);
    }
    return $out; // this one is still an array
}

$data = codeOutput($codeCount, $blockCount, $digitsCount);
```

---

Then to write the data to a file...

```
file_put_contents('keys.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $data));
```

Or output for HTML

```
echo implode('<br>', $data);
```